# Use JSON instead HTML for access denied on some custom paths

Tags: routes, 8

I create a small API for one project using Bathic Authentication. The API consists of some custom paths defined in routes in a custom module. Using JsonResponse() in the controller we send back a JSON object with data.

But in case the user does not have permissions to access the path the route gives back the 404 HTML page. How can I tell Drupal to return a JSON object for my API paths under every circumstances?

Another example: we defined just to accept GET in the route. Using POST will return a HTML error page - we want Drupal to send back JSON with error information.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal returns the 404 in the format requested, so adding the query string `?_format=json` to the request should return a JSON response under any circumstances. If Drupal doesn't detect the format it uses HTML by default. You could either help Drupal detecting the format in a request subscriber or implement an exception subscriber to return JSON exceptions similar to [ExceptionJsonSubscriber::on4xx](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21EventSubscriber%21ExceptionJsonSubscriber.php/function/ExceptionJsonSubscriber%3A%3Aon4xx/8.5.x) for your API paths.

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes ?_format=json gives a strange error back (somethinkg like "format json unknown/ not allowed"). Could you help me with describing an event subscriber which handles returning always JSON on some paths?

Comment: You could copy or extend the mentioned ExceptionJsonSubscriber, increase the priority and add `html` to the handled format or empty the formats to handle all. Then check in the event listener for the path and return a json response.

Comment: @TobiasKrause With `_format=json`, the route needs to accept JSON as format, or Drupal will throw an error saying the format is not allowed. That is understandable, as you cannot request to output JSON to a route returning HTML markup.